# Prove that the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \log \left| \dfrac{x-1}{x} \right|dx $ diverges

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I have to prove that the integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \log \left| \dfrac{x-1}{x} \right|dx$$ diverges.

Actually, I want to prove that $f(x)=\log \left| \dfrac{x-1}{x}\right|$ does not belong to the space $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. However, I got stuck as I don't know how to begin.

The only idea I know is that equality
$$\dfrac{x}{x+1} < \log(1+x) < x, \forall x > 0.$$
But it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Please give me some hints. Any help or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! hint: have you tried to compute what happens to $f(x)$ in a neighborhood of zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remark that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} x\log\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=-1$ by applying Hospital theorem. Thus, $f$ is not integrable in $+\infty$.